# How to automate commit of code architecture to an Azure DevOps Repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-commit, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on an automation, that will create repositories and pipelines based on standards and requirements. To create repositories and pipelines, I have used Azure DevOps REST APIs and it is working fine.

Now, along with creating repo, the requirement is to also commit a code structure - basic architecture of application - as initial commit. Using Azure DevOps REST API, I can find that we need to mention file by file and there is no option for bulk commit - [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

I have also tried forking the seed/base repo while creating the new one but this will also bring the commit history and repo properties of base repo to new one and it is not expected. Also, the icon of forked repo is different and I believe, it is treated differently than other repo.

Can anyone please guide me on how to approach this requirement and how can it be implemented - to automate commiting a bulk code (base architecture) to a newly created repo?

Comment: You can create the repository with "Azure DevOps REST API" and you can commit/push with git cli.

Comment: Create the Devops repo empty. Then create a repo locally (eg. using a template: `git init name --template dir`: see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory)), set the new DevOps repo as a remote, and push,

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you could create an empty Azure DevOps repo, then create a repo locally, e.g. using [`git init name --template dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory).

Then [Set the new DevOps repo as a remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes):

```
git remote add origin xxxxxx
```

And push:

```
git add .   
git commit    
git push
```